# Infinite Scroll with JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

With this code i get the first 2 results of my JSON array. How can I "load more" by scrolling?

```
   function suchen() {

      var suche = document.getElementById("mysearch").value;

      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=' + suche + '&callback=?',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function daten (response) {

              $( 'ul#suche li' ).remove();
              var i = 0;
              response.forEach(function(data) {

                  if(i >= 2)  
                      return false;

                  $('ul#suche').append('<li class="item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + data.title + '</div></div></li>');
                  i++;

              })
          }
      });
   }
```

How can load the next (3 - 4 for example) items by scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Before that, I'd mention that if you use `id` in selector you don't need to specify node type.

I mean use `$('#suche')` instead of `$('ul#suche')`

---

When it comes to infinite scroll, you should definitely specify items amount in your ajax call to get a exact chunk you need. Maybe to specify `from` and `amount` if your API gives a possibility.

Like this:

```
var from = 0
var amount = 2

var callApi = function (from, amount) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=' + suche + '&from' + from + '&amount=' + amount + '&callback=?',
    success: function (response) {
      response.forEach(function(data) {
        $('#suche').append(
          '<li class="item-content">' +
            '<div class="item-inner">' +
              '<div class="item-title">' + data.title + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</li>'
        );
      });

      // increase from on each call
      from += amount;
    }
  });
};

// call it
callApi(from, amount);
```

Then you need to add `scroll` eventListener and when last element appears on window canvas, call it again.

```
var lastChild, lastChildPosition, bottomPosition, bottomPosition

$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
  lastChild = $('#suche li:last-child');
  lastChildPosition = lastChild.scrollTop();

  scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  bottomPosition = scrollTop + $(window).height();

  // call it again
  if (bottomPosition > lastChildPosition) {
    callApi(from, amount);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I answered on the top because in the comments it is difficult to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I try to build a version with Wordpress which is based on your idea:

```
 function suchen_api(lastindex) {


  var suche = document.getElementById("mysearch").value;
  var offset = lastindex;
  var showposts = 2;


  $.ajax({
 url: 'http://XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=' + suche + '&offset=' + offset + '  &showposts=' + showposts + '&callback=?',
 type: "GET",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(response){

    response.forEach(function(data) {

 $('ul#suche').append('<li class="item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + data.title + '</div></div></li>');

 myApp.hideIndicator(); // Preloader geht aus

 $$('.infinite-scroll-preloader').remove();
    })
 }
 });

 }



 function suchen() {

 $( '#suche li' ).remove();

 var startindex = 0;

suchen_api(startindex);

 }


 // on Scroll

 $$('.infinite-scroll').on('infinite', function () {

  var startindex = $("ul#suche li").length;

  suchen_api(startindex);

  })
```

There is only one problem. Sometimes it shows me the last one doubled. Do you have an idea?